# Change submit button opacity on input :focus

Tags: javascript, css, forms, input, opacity

What I have is a search bar and an image as the `submit` button. I want the opacity of the `submit` button to be `0.5` in its normal state, and `1.0` when the search bar is on `:focus`.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id='searchThis' action='/search' method='get' style='display: inline;'>
<input id='searchBox' name='q' onblur='if(this.value==&apos;&apos;)this.value=this.defaultValue;' onfocus='if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=&apos;&apos;;' style='display:inline;font-family:Segoe UI, Microsoft Tai Le, trebuchet MS,&apos;lucida grande&apos;;width: 155px;color:#636363;' type='text' value='Search' vinput=''/>
<input id='submitsearch' alt='Search' height='20px' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Ab4nALwSEdw/T4LI1pym1LI/AAAAAAAABBA/_oQltx3svas/s320/search.png' style='display:inline; padding-left: 10px; margin-top:1px; position: absolute; opacity:0.5;' title='Search' type='image' width='20px'/>
</form>
```

But I don't know whether I should be using CSS or Javascript and I'm not very good at either.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS:

```
#submitsearch {
  opacity: 0.5;

     -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#searchBox:focus + #submitsearch {
  opacity: 1.0
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for! Thank you, but is there any way for it to fade in on `:focus` and out back to it's normal state?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css

```css
#submitsearch:hover {opacity:0.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS:

```css
#submitsearch { opacity: 0.75; }
#submitsearch:hover, #submitsearch:active { opacity: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I salute the CSS3 solution of Newtron - I usually encourage jQuery use for a larger cross-browser compatibility;
Here's how I would usually handle this situation:
http://jsfiddle.net/earthdesigner/qc6Qf/1/